# How to center UILabel using frame: CGRect

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to place the label at the centre of the view. However, its always off centre. Why is this?

This is the code:

```
lazy var readyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: screenWidth*0.5 - screenWidth*0.3, y: screenHeight*0.5, width: screenWidth*0.6, height: screenHeight*0.1 ))

readyLabel.textAlignment = .center
readyLabel.text = "3"
readyLabel.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
readyLabel.alpha = 0
readyLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Futura-Bold", size: (75.0/375)*screenWidth)
readyLabel.sizeToFit()
self.view.addSubview(readyLabel)
```

Comment: You give the label constant size and position and then you call `sizeToFit` which changes the size, therefore also removing it from the centre. Remove that call and ideally use constraints instead of this magic that won't really work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
label.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width  / 2, y: view.frame.size.height / 2)
```

Or

```
child.center = parent.convert(parent.center, from:parent.superview)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this **after** the last line:

```
readyLabel.center = self.view.convertPoint(self.view.center, from: self.view.superview)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the line:

readyLabel.sizeToFit()